# Удаление символа из строки

Tags: java, строки

Здравствуйте, вот такая проблема. Как из строки удалить символы [], если ] ещё можно удалить, то с [ я не справился. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: есть несколько подходов реализации: 1 - использовать регулярное выражение (необходимо экранировать специальные символы), например с помощью String.replaceAll 2 - формировать новую строку на основе старой не включая удаляемые символы (например с помощью цикла)

Answer (score 3):

```
final String str = "Здравствуйте, вот такая проблема. Как из строки удалить символы [], если ] ещё можно удалить, то с [ я не справился. Заранее спасибо!";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(\\s+\\[|\\[|\\s+\\]|\\])",""));
```

Вывод:

> Здравствуйте, вот такая проблема. Как из строки удалить символы, если ещё можно удалить, то с я не справился. Заранее спасибо!

**UPD:**
Изменил регулярку, чтобы убирала пробелы и т. д. до скобок:
`символы_[, если_] ещё можно удалить, то с_[`
`_` - просто показываю, что тут пробелы, которые удалять нужно тоже.

Answer (score 2):

У меня вышло чуть больше строк.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word = "he[]llo w[]orld";
    char[] chArray = word.toCharArray();
    String str = "";
    for(int i = 0; i<chArray.length; i++){
       if(chArray[i] == '[' || chArray[i] == ']'){
          continue;
       }    
       str += chArray[i];
    }
System.out.println(str);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Без создания лишних объектов String

```
String test = "Hello[[]]] world[[";
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       sb.append(test);
       int i = 0;
       while ((i = sb.indexOf("[", i) ) >= 0) {
           sb.replace(i, i + 1, "");
       }
        while ((i = sb.indexOf("]", i) ) >= 0) {
            sb.replace(i, i + 1, "");
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
```